# Can't add xCode 4.2 project to repository (and get it working)

Tags: xcode, git

I created a new project and all files are added to the projectfile.

I 'cd' to my project root and does the following steps:

1. `rm -rf .git` (remove all left overs if any).
2. `git init`
3. `git add .`
4. `git -m "initial commit"`

Then I load my project, and make some changes to my code. xCode 4.2 notifies this correctly by adding the 'm' (modified) icon in the project explorer.

I right click the modified file and choose "***Source control->Commit selected files***" and it says: **The working copy "of my project" could not be found. Please verify that the working copy is reachable and try again.**

The entry I just created is red in Organizer, any ideas whats wrong? Have I missed a step?

Comment: I rebooted my iMac and it seemed to help. Fantastic, I switched to mac to get rid of all the reboots.

Comment: It seems a bug to XCode, when the project path have ~.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using built-in GIT support inside xCode, not a command line git.
On project creation page, where you select folder to store project, there is checkbox you mark if you want to use GIT.

All other GIT stuff are accessible view File->Source Control menu.

So, try re-creating your project but make sure you've selected GIT support.

Comment: xCode pick ups .git folders correctly - This should work, apple even suggesting using the following commands in the help section of the organizer.