# xcode, error when commiting to github repository

Tags: xcode, git

I am developing an iphone project on xcode and I'd like to commit my code to a git repository on github. When I select the "commit" option within xcode I got the following error message:

```
The working copy "iphone" could not be reached.
Please verify that the working copy is reachable and try again.
```

I checked in the repository option and deleted the repository I had set up at the beginning. My code is under git and I have added the remote origin but still... it does not work from xcode (I have to commit and push from command line which is working fine).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure this isn't about some locked resource which prevents XCode to access your local repo.
For instance, in "[Can't add xCode 4.2 project to repository (and get it working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027949/cant-add-xcode-4-2-project-to-repository-and-get-it-working)", a reboot actually helped...

Comment: I ran into this same issue with Xcode 4.6.2 when trying to set up the repository to work with Github.  Rebooting fixed it. Thanks!